# Create a Map in Thymeleaf html

Tags: thymeleaf

Currently I have created a fragment which takes a list of properties and urls in order to create a menu:

```
menuFrag (thymeleafMap)
```

I wanted to populate this in the front end but I am not sure how to make directly in thyme leaf

```
<div th:replace="fragments/menu :: menuFrag ((<#{menu.item1},@(/menuItem1)><(#{menu.item2},@(/menuItem2)>))"></div>
```

Is there a way to do this or would it I have to pass this information down from the controller?

Also if there was a way for me to just pass in two array's that would also work.

Answer (score 10):

It is actually possible to write map literals in thymeleaf, like this:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/menu :: menuFrag (menu=${ {{item:'Item1',url:'/menuItem1'},{item:'Item2',url:'/menuItem2'}} })"></div>
```

(Note that it is in fact a map nested into a list to be able to iterate over the outer one. Thymeleaf (or should I say SpringEL) seems to produce LinkedHashMap for the map and ArrayList for the list according to my observations)

You can then iterate over the items in your menu fragment like this:

```
<ul th:each="item: $(menu)">
  <li><a th:text="${item.item}" th:href="@{${item.url}}" />Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understand your question right.

First you can create a `Map<key, value>`, key is the menu name (`#{menu.item1}`) and the value is the URL (`@(/menuItem1)`) in your controller where the journey begin.

Controller looks something like this:

```
Map<String, String> menu = new HashMap<String, String>();
menu.put("Google", "www.google.de");
menu.put("Yahoo", "www.yahoo.de");
menu.put("Apple", "www.apple.de");
menu.put("Microsoft", "www.microsoft.de");
model.addAttribute("menuMap", menu);
```

Second you have the two templates, the first is your `main` and the second the `menu` fragment. In the main you have to "access" the map from your controller and call the 'menu' fragment, like this:

```
<div th:include="menu :: copy(${menuMap})"></div>
```

in the second template, `menu` fragment you take the map that you get from the `main` and iterate over this, like the following:

```
...
<div th:fragment="copy(menuMap)" >
    Hello World
    <ul th:each="instance : ${menuMap}">
       <li><a th:text="${instance.key}" th:href="@{${instance.value}}">key</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

That's all, with this you get your menu.

Comment: Yea reading it my question was probably not very clear. I want to be able to create the map directly on the .html page without having to pass it in through a controller. 

So create a map in thymeleaf without ever touching a controller at all. After doing a little research I am not sure it is possible.

Comment: You right, in thymeleaf you there are no possibility to create a map. Why you would to this? logic for what the user can see or not can be control via the controller. But an other solution to create a map in the html is via javascript.

Comment: I have a menu fragment that is shared over multiple pages. I would like it to be dynamic depending on which page you are on. The best way I could think of doing this was by passing a map into the menu fragment and I don't really want to have to pass that in from the controller. Maybe I will look at javascript.